# Objective-C programming to call an application from another apps

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to develop an application that needs to call another application which is in the local host.I have already posted the same question in the stackoverflow and i got the anwer and implemented it according to it. But i did not get the ouput in the iPhone simulator.Guide me in the coding what is the mistake such that it appears while debugging as

> Blockquote

Error from Debugger: Failed to lauch simulated application: iPhone Simulator failed to install the application.

```
#import "ModuleManagerAppDelegate.h"   
@implementation ModuleManagerAppDelegate 
@synthesize window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
 NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"backgroundcolor:backgroundcolor"];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL]; 
 [window makeKeyAndVisible];  
 [myURL release];
}
- (void)dealloc
{    
 [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

This is the calling application and i am calling the BackgroundColor as the called application.I have also registered BackgroundColor in the info.plist.This is my info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
     <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
     <string>English</string>
     <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
     <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
     <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
     <string></string>
     <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
     <string>com.yourcompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>
     <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
     <string>6.0</string>
     <key>CFBundleName</key>
     <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
     <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
     <string>APPL</string>
     <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
     <string>????</string>
     <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
     <string>1.0</string>
     <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
     <true/>
     <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
     <string>MainWindow</string>
     <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
     <array>
      <dict>
       <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
       <string>com.xxx.backgroundcolor.xcodeproj</string>
       <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
       <array>
        <string>backgroundcolor.xcodeproj</string>
       </array>
      </dict>
     </array>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

This is my called application(BackgroundColor.m)

```
#import "BackgroundColorAppDelegate.h"

@implementation BackgroundColorAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize Orange,Green,Yellow,Blue,Red;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *) application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
if([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"backgroundcolor"])
 {
-(IBAction)doOrange
{
 window.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
}
-(IBAction)doBlue
{
 window.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
}
-(IBAction)doGreen
{
 window.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
}
-(IBAction)doRed
{
 window.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
}
-(IBAction)doYellow
{
 window.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
}
```

}

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Something's wrong with the code of your BackgroundColor application.  You've wrapped a series of method implementations (-doOrange, -doBlue, etc.) within another method implementation (-application:handleOpenURL:).  The compiler should be giving you errors about this.  You need to move those method implementations out of that other method, and use a switch statement to call the methods.  Right now, this code is nonsensical.

Answer (score 0):

A first thing to try is to get rid of the point in your URL scheme. Use `backgroundcolor` instead of `backgroundcolor.xcodeproj`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Kindly also answer for my questions..Pls help me .............